# NSFetchedResultsController controllerDidChangeContent not called

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having troubles having my `NSFetchedResultsController` updated when something changes in my data. My simplified model looks like this

[image: Model]

And I have a query to list all the `PSWeapons` of a `PSPlayer` that has its `PSMetaData`'s attribute set to `YES`

```
NSPredicate *selected = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"player.metadata.selected == %@", @YES];
NSFetchRequest *request = [PSWeapon MR_requestAllWithPredicate:selected];
request.sortDescriptors = @[];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                      cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

The first query works fine but the `-[NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate controllerDidChangeContent:]` is not called when another player is selected.

I even ended up posting my own notification when a new player is selected and calling again `[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];` when it is posted but this does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

cheers

Comment: The fetchedResultsController will only keep track of changes to the entities which are the subject of the underlying fetch request - in your case `PSWeapon` objects.  Changes to the objects linked by a relationship will not be detected, even though they affect the outcome of the predicate.  That said, your alternative approach ought to work - can you post the associated code?

Comment: Actually it does work. When selecting a new player, I was calling the `-[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]` to "force" the update and relying on `-[NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate controllerDidChangeContent:]` to update the UI but the latter is not called for the initial fetch. So I just had to refresh the UI after calling the `performFetch`.

Comment: Another approach, instead of posting my own notification, is to have another `NSFetchedResultsController` that queries only the selected player. When this fetchedResultController changes, I can re-fetch my weaponFetchedResultController